# Initialize env.rb from unit test in ruby

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, cucumber

How do I initialize `env.rb` from `Test::Unit::TestCase`. I want to be able to unit test my ruby methods in my Ruby/Cucumber app and `env.rb` does a lot of setup before hand.

Simplified example:

env.rb

```
require 'logger'

$LOG = Logger.new(STDOUT)
```

HelloWorld.rb

```
class HelloWorld
  def say_hi
    greeting = 'Hello World'

    $LOG.info greeting

    greeting
  end
 end
```

TestHelloWorld.rb

```
require 'hello_world'

class TestHelloWorld < Test::Unit::TestCase

  def test_say_hi
    assert_equal('Hello World', HelloWorld.new.say_hi)
  end
end
```

running `TestHellowWorld` gives `NoMethodError: undefined method`info' for nil:NilClass`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the Test::Unit script directory and the cucumber project are siblings, you can use `relative require` to require `env.rb`.  For example:

**/cucumber_project/features/support/env.rb**

```
require 'logger'
$LOG = Logger.new(STDOUT)
```

**hello_world.rb**

```
class HelloWorld
  def say_hi
    greeting = 'Hello World'
    $LOG.info greeting
    greeting
  end
end
```

**test.rb**

```
require_relative 'hello_world'
require_relative '../cucumber_project/features/support/env'
require 'test/unit'

class TC_HelloWorld < Test::Unit::TestCase

  def test_say_hi
    assert_equal('Hello World', HelloWorld.new.say_hi)
  end

end
```

Comment: Works the way I asked the question but doesn't fix my main problem. I need to dig deeper to figure out how to better ask. Thank you!